# Converting ajax api post to $http post in angular js getting a 404

Tags: angularjs, api

I'm trying to create a chat app where you can log into the incontact chat api (discard the weatherApp naming.. ).
This is the API documentation for the incontact chat api:

```
function startAgentSession() {
var startSessionPayload = {
    'stationId': 'string',
    'stationPhoneNumber': 'string',
    'inactivityTimeout': 'integer - 30-300, or 0 for default',
    'inactivityForceLogout': 'boolean',
    'asAgentId': 'integer'
}
$.ajax({
    //The baseURI variable is created by the result.base_server_base_uri
    //which is returned when getting a token and should be used to create the URL base
    'url': baseURI + 'services/{version}/agent-sessions',
    'type': 'POST',
    'headers': {
        //Use access_token previously retrieved from inContact token service
        'Authorization': 'bearer ' + accessToken,
        'content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'data': JSON.stringify(startSessionPayload),
    'success': function (result) {
        //Process success actions
        return result;
    },
    'error': function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //Process error actions
        return false;
    }
});
```

``}

This is my attempt to convert in angular js, but for some reason I keep getting a 404, however, I'm at a loss for what I've done wrong..

```
weatherApp.controller('launchedController', ['$scope', '$http', '$document', function ($scope, $http, $document) {

$scope.clientResult = {};

$document.ready(function () {
    var query_string = {};
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }
    if (typeof(query_string.access_token) != "undefined") {
        var result = {};
        result.state = query_string.state;
        result.scope = query_string.scope;
        result.access_token = query_string.access_token;
        result.expires_in = query_string.expires_in;
        result.resource_server_base_uri = query_string.resource_server_base_uri;
        result.token_type = query_string.token_type;
    }

    $scope.clientResult = result;

});

console.log($scope.clientResult);

    $scope.startSessionPayload = {
        'stationPhoneNumber': '55555555555',
        'inactivityTimeout': '0',
        'inactivityForceLogout': 'false'
    };

$http({
    url: JSON.stringify($scope.clientResult.resource_server_base_uri)  + '/services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
    method: "POST",
    headers:{'Authorization': 'bearer ' + $scope.clientResult.access_token,'content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: JSON.stringify($scope.startSessionPayload)
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    consoloe.log('data', $scope.data)
}).error(function(status) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

}]);

Answer (score 0):

400 error is bad request. My guess is

replace

```
{
    url: JSON.stringify($scope.clientResult.resource_server_base_uri)  + '/services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
    method: "POST",
    headers:{'Authorization': 'bearer ' + $scope.clientResult.access_token,'content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: JSON.stringify($scope.startSessionPayload)
}
```

with

```
{
    url: JSON.stringify($scope.clientResult.resource_server_base_uri)  + '/services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
    method: "POST",
    headers:{'Authorization': 'bearer ' + $scope.clientResult.access_token,'content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: $scope.startSessionPayload
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. it was actually a 404 (typo). I've tried with and without the JSON.stringify, the attempted url seems to remain the same..  all of my data seems to be correct..

Comment: 404 means resource not found error. Can you verify any handlar present to accept incoming request @ /services/v6.0/agent-sessions

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but how would I verify that?

Comment: http://localhost:63342/Call_cntr/client/https%3a%2f%2fapi-c7.incontact.com%2finContactAPI%2fservices/v6.0/agent-sessions   : This is the fails url it is attempting to hit.

Comment: Yeah. that's what I'm trying to debug now.. I can't understand how that's being added to the uri...

Comment: it's not on the url in the $http post, I"m now sure how that's getting attached..

Comment: what does $scope.clientResult.resource_server_base_uri contain?

Comment: resource_server_base_uri: "https%3a%2f%2fapi-c7.incontact.com%2finContactAPI%2f"       It contains this string, which is what should be concatenated to the rest of the required url .